# Q: Python (pandas or other) - I need to "flatten" a data file from many rows, few columns to 1 row many columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to "flatten" a data file from many rows, few columns to 1 row many columns.

I currently have a dataframe in pandas (loaded from Excel) and ultimately need to change the way the data is displayed so I can accumulate large amounts of data in a logical manner. The below tables are an attempt at illustrating my requirements.

From:

```
         1      2
Ryan     0.706  0.071
Chad     0.151  0.831
Stephen  0.750  0.653
```

To:

```
1_Ryan  1_Chad  1_Stephen  2_Ryan  2_Chad  2_Stephen
0.706   0.151   0.75       0.071   0.831   0.653
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: You can use Excel VBA to create a nested for loop that will do what you need.

Comment: whats wrong with just transposing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One line, for fun

```
df.unstack().pipe(
    lambda s: pd.DataFrame([s.values], columns=s.index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format))
)

   1_Ryan  1_Chad  1_Stephen  2_Ryan  2_Chad  2_Stephen
0   0.706   0.151       0.75   0.071   0.831      0.653
```

Comment: @Wen, and now you have!  Think of all the fun things you can do now (-:

Comment: df.unstack().pipe(
    lambda s: pd.DataFrame([s.values], columns=s.index.map(' '.join))
) Why use format over join?  Oh just incase those numbers are integers and not strings.

Comment: I accidentally deleted comment >.<  It breaks if those are ints in the column header.  `df.rename(columns=int).unstack().pipe( lambda s: pd.DataFrame([s.values], columns=s.index.map(' '.join)))` produces a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`.  Using format covers my behind.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use `stack`, `swaplevel`, `to_frame`, and `T`:

```
df_out = df.stack().swaplevel(1,0).to_frame().T.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Or better yet,(using @piRSquared unstack solution)

```
df_out = df.unstack().to_frame().T

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)

df_out
```

Output:

```
   1_Chad  1_Ryan  1_Stephen  2_Chad  2_Ryan  2_Stephen
0   0.151   0.706       0.75   0.831   0.071      0.653
```